# What is the running time of merge sort for these inputs

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, big-o

I am trying to determine the running time in Big O of merge sort for:

(A) sorted input

(B) reverse-ordered input

(C) random input

My answer is that it would take O(n lgn) for all three scenarios, since regardless of the default order of the input, merge sort will always divide the input into the smallest unit of 1 element.  Then it will compare each element with each element in the adjacent list to sort and merge the two adjacent lists.  It will continue to do this until finally all the elements are sorted and merged.

That said, all we really need to find then is the Big O complexity of merge sort in general, since the worst, average, and best cases will all take the same time.

My question is, can somebody tell me if my answers are correct, and if so, explain why the Big O complexity of merge sort ends up being O(n lgn)?

Comment: There are many answers on so that answer your queries. Also, you are totally correct that in all cases, time taken will be similar.

Comment: The big O complexity is O(n log(n)) because that's how many moves are performed between the original and the working array. There are ceil[log2(n)]  (ceiling is rounded up) passes for n elements, and each pass moves n elements, for a total of O(n log(n)) moves. The number of compares is a bit less for random data, n/2 log(n) for ordered or reversed data best case, but the 1/2 factor is a constant, so the overall complexity remains O(n log(n)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on your implementation of Merge Sort.
When naively implemented, merge sort indeed uses O(n * log n) time as it will always divide the input down to the smallest unit. However, there's a specific implementation called **Natural Merge Sort** that will keep numbers in their correct order if they're already ordered in the input array by essentially first looking at the given input and deciding which parts need to be ordered, that is, divided and later merged again.

Natural Merge Sort will only take O(n) time for an ordered input and in general be faster for a random input than for a reverse-ordered input. In the latter two cases, runtime will be O(n * log n).

To answer your last question, I'll look at the "normal" Mergesort; the explanation is easier that way.

Note that Mergesort can be visualized as a binary tree where in the root we have the whole input, on the next layer the two halves you get from dividing the input once, on the third layer we have four quarters and so on... On the last layer we finally have individual numbers.

[image]

Then note that the whole tree is O(log n) deep (this can also be proved mathematically). On each layer we have to make some comparisons and swaps on n numbers in total - this is because the total amount of numbers on a layer doesn't decrease when we go down the tree. In the picture, we need to do comparisons and swaps on 8 numbers on each layer. The way Mergesort works, we'll actually have to do *exactly* 8 comparisons and *up to* 8 swaps per layer. If we have an input of length n instead of 8, we'll need n comparisons and up to n swaps per layer (this is O(n)). We have O(log n) layers, so the whole runtime will be O(n * log n).

Comment: Standard merge sort only uses n/2 compares per pass if data is ordered or reversed. Random data will need more compares.  For random data, merging of individual numbers takes n/2 compares. Worst case merging of pairs of numbers takes 3n/4 compares. Worst case merging sets of 4 numbers takes 7n/8 compares. Worst case on sets of 8, 15n/16, ... and so on, converging towards n as the sets gets larger. Standard merge sort number of moves between original and temp array is always the same, n log(n).

Comment: Variations of natural merge sort also handle reverse order sequences, also taking O(n) time in the special case where the entire array is reverse order. If the entire file is not ordered (forward or reversed, then the log factor is increased, but it's still (n logx(n)), where logx(n) is the number of passes needed to sort the data.